# Main Window resize in Python with Qt

Tags: python, resize, pyside, qmainwindow, pyuic

I have a gui in `ui_main.py` file (designed in Qt Designer). I load it in my main `*.py` file in this way:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
...
```

ui_main.py file:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(667, 559)
```

I need to resize my main window during application start. My main problem is that I can't get access to Main window object.

```
 self.ui.MainWindow.resize(300,300)
 AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'MainWindow'
```

If I add to `ui_main.py` file:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.uiui = MainWindow
```

I can resize my main window with:

```
self.ui.uiui.resize(300,300)
```

But I know that it's very bad to edit generated ui file. How can I resize my main window without editing a gui file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ui module created by `pyuic` (via Qt Designer) is just a simple helper class with a couple of initialization methods.

Both methods take an instance of the top-level ui class from Qt Designer (usually a `QMainWindow`), and then *add* the all the ui elements *to* that instance. This ensures that everything created in Qt Designer is accessible from the top-level widget.

So your `MyForm` subclass passes `self` (an instance of `QMainWindow`) to `setupUi`, which then becomes the `MainWindow` variable you see in your ui file.

This means you can resize your main window by simply doing:

```
self.resize(300, 300)
```